# Get Printer MIB with JAVA

Tags: java, printing, snmp, mib

I doing **java** program to get **printer's MIB** in a **Network**.. How can I get the **printer's** **MIB** data through **java**."

Thank you..

Comment: Do you actually want to get the MIB or retrieve SNMP data? (The MIB is a separate entity)

Comment: get the MIB with the printer IP Adress.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [SNMP4J](http://www.snmp4j.org/) libraries and [docs](http://www.snmp4j.org/doc/index.html).